# Flagging very old questions

Tags: discussion, flagging, on-topic

I have today been flagging some very old questions that are very low quality. The reason I'm doing this is because they still show up in the "unanswered" section of the site, but they are very unlikely to ever get any meaningful discussion on them.

Is this a waste of time? Should I just leave them be? I don't have sufficient rep to close them myself obviously.

Comment: My advice would be to you always track the feedback received to have raised the flag. If they have been marked "helpful" by many users then, you are ok. If some of them have been declined try to understand why. + 1 for asking.

Comment: Thanks, yes. So far I'm mostly being helpful apparently. It just seems like good hygiene to try to close old, unanswered, low quality questions so the good ones are easier to find.

Comment: This is a good question, & @AndreSilva has some good advice here. One note: I believe the "helpful" pretty much only comes from the moderators. Personally, it seems reasonable to me to clean up old, low quality threads that don't have any answers & aren't likely to get any.

Comment: Agreed - it never hurts to clean out old, low quality stuff that isn't helping anyone.

Comment: I'm also trying to move very good quality comments to answers using the community wiki tag. This was suggested on the Math.SE "Great Unanswered Questions Crusade" as a course of action (if I recall correctly).